# How to preserve Vaadin Tree container items order?

Tags: java, tree, containers, vaadin

I have `Vaadin 7` `Tree` with `HierarchicalCOntainer` which contains items in some order (reordered through `.moveAfterSibling()`.

When I try to get their `ID` collection I get them into order I have originally inserted, not the order they are shown.

I have checked both `container.getItemIds()` and `.firstItemId()` / `.nextItemId()`. Both do not match the order I see on the screen.

What do I do wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking to `HierarchicalCOntainer` source I have figured how `.moveAfterSibling()` works. The only remedy is to get `root` elements list:

```
container.rootItemIds()
```